# apt-get not adding to menu?

Tags: debian, lxde

So I'm running Debian, with lxde.
apt-getting things I want, and I felt the strange urge top play kbounce.
so I used "apt-get install kbounce"
and it installed fine.
(I had the menu open at the time, 'cos I was wondering if it would just appear)
but it didn't.
It runs when I go run, and type "kbounce" but it's not in the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason or another, your games submenu wasn't added.
If you add another game, the games menu will be added, and you will be able to see your new game and kbounce.
happy gaming

Answer (score 0):

Debian has a "menu" package to handle menus for *all* desktops and window managers, and an "`update-menus`" command to update those menus.  This command is *supposed* to be run automatically on installation of a package with new menu entries, but you can also do it yourself if your menus get garbled somehow.

Answer (score 0):

For Gnome (sorry, no idea about KDE): some things install their menu item into the Gnome menu hierarchy, and some into the Debian menu hierarchy.  Have you checked both places ?  (If you can't see the Debian menu in your Gnome applications menu, you can enable it in preferences somewhere).